# GetelementbyId from selected Value

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a script, which Updates a table in a Mysql Database with GET Parameters.
I want to execute that script with javscript and a Button. But that Button doesnt work.

```
$abfrage = "SELECT * FROM pending";
$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
echo '<script>
function showid(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getusr.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
function statusa(str)
{
xmlhttp.open("GET","getusr.php?statusa="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>';

echo '<form><select id="selectid" name="id" onchange="showid(this.value)" size=1>';
echo '<option value="">ID ausw&auml;hlen</option>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
{
 echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">' . $row->id . '</option>';
 }
 echo '</select><input type="button" name="button1" value="accept" onClick="statusa(getElementById("selectid").selectedIndex)" /></form>';
 echo '<div id="txtHint"></div>';
 }
 else
  {
  echo '<html><form action="setstatus.php" method="post"><input type="password" name="pw"><input type="submit" value="submit"></form></html>';
  }
```

The getusr.php Script works, when I access it with the GET Parameters only. BUt the button doesnt work. The Button should retrieve the ID from the selected Item in the dropdown list.

Regards an thanks for your help in advance

Comment: You have an `else` but I don't see the `if` that it should go with.

Comment: The if statement is one line above.. I didn't copy it, thats only the password protection

Answer (score 0):

The button retrieves the index of the selected option, not the value of the selected option. Also, you need to escape the quotes around `selectid`, otherwise the first one ends the string at the beginning of the attribute.

```
onClick="statusa(document.getElementById(\"selectid\").value)
```

Comment: thank you, but it still doesnt work :/
I tried to capture the GET parameters with livehttpheaders but there are no GET Parameters set.

Comment: It should be `document.getElementById`. Have you been checking your Javascript console for errors?

Comment: Nope I didnt, wait a sec.

Comment: How do I open the JS Console?

Comment: If I press the "Accept" Button, the Console doesnt show anything.

Comment: `statusa` uses the variable `xmlhttp` without ever assigning anything to it.

Comment: how do I assign it? and the showid function works too? there is also nothing assigned?

Comment: `showid` has `xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest` in it. You need similar code in `statusa`.

Comment: Can you help me with this?